# Where can I see a list of burninated tags?

Tags: support, burninate-system

There is a lot of discussion here about tags getting burninated for one reason or another.

It's good to see a strong community working behind the scenes to keep the main site working well.

But is there anywhere that I can look to see a list of all those ex-tags?

Two reasons for wanting to know:

- Curiosity. I just want to know what's been done in the past, without having to trawl through the meta questions for each one.
- Let's say hypothetically I were to write a piece of software useful enough to the dev community that people might want to ask questions about it on SO... if I've given it a name that happens to correspond to a tag that was previously burninated, it might make things difficult for people to ask questions.
- No, actually, that second point isn't really all that likely, so uh, yeah, it's really just curiosity.  :)

Comment: Another possible reason would be you stumbled upon a tag and have found it useless and wish to get it burninated, so you wish to make a [tag:burninate-request] but first want to ensure it hasn't been asked in the past.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can search for [`is:q [burninate-request][status-completed]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[burninate-request][status-completed]), here on Meta, which will get you a list of burnination requests which have been marked as being completed. Not every completed burnination request will get tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), but most do.

Comment: Hmm. Okay, this does work. I was more thinking about whether it would be possible to directly query the DB to get the actual list of burnt tags. This answer does give results, but as you say it's not definitive. I'll accept the answer if nothing else comes up though. :)

Comment: @Simba, There's the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), for querying the DB, but which unfortunately does not have deleted stuff (which includes tags, I'd guess.)

Comment: @Simba Burninations are not directly logged, because a lot of them get completed by the community just editing the tags off all the questions over time until the tag no longer exists. Theoretically most of the tags will still be present in post history events, so you could browse through post histories and compile a list of all the tags you found which *don't* have an actual tag entry, but that would be a rather large project you probably wouldn't be able to do in Data Explorer. This method also wouldn't include tag merges, which just overwrites the tag without creating a history event.

Answer (score 7):

"Burnination" is, in most cases, not a permanent event. It's usually accomplished by having users go through and remove a tag from every question that it was on, and it can be reversed at any time by adding that tag to a question to recreate it. (There's a reputation threshold for creating a tag that doesn't currently exist, but it's pretty low: 1500.)

What you may be thinking of is tag blacklisting. That's used pretty rarely, and usually only for tags that are uselessly generic, e.g. "problem", "programming", "computer", "homework", *etc*. If your software happens to have a name that coincides with one of these generic blacklisted tags, it will probably be appropriate to disambiguate its name in the tag.

Comment: Ah. Thank you. Now I see where my confusion was. I thought that burnination and blacklisting were the same thing. In fact, I wasn't even aware of blacklisting as separate thing. Thank you. I've up-voted your answer, although in fairness I must mark @JonasCz's answer as accepted since he was the one who gave me the actual answer. Thank you though.