# Can I find out the reason behind a specific tag purge if this info is (seemingly) not present on meta?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, burninate-system

I was answering a [NETCONF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NETCONF) protocol ([RFC6241](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6241)) related question yesterday and wanted to retag it with the `netconf` tag, which I clearly remember as once being in existence. No such tag exists anymore (I became aware of this a while ago, but didn't act upon it). The only reason I'd become aware of mentioned question is another tag I'm following, which is closely related to the field, but has nothing to do with the question. A user was actually forced to use this other tag to attract attention of a limited number of other users able to answer his/her answer (probably not the first case).

How can I find out what happened to `netconf` and the reasons behind it? Would I be wrong to bring it back to life? I mean..it must have been removed for a reason and may happen again (I hate being Sisyphus). While at a slow pace, there are clearly [new](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=netconf) questions emerging that could use this tag.

[This discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321676/where-can-i-see-a-list-of-burninated-tags) provides a way to find what I would like to see, but searching for this specific tag gives zero results.
[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250934/878469) mentions that there should have been a discussion here on meta. Where is it?

By [slugster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254893/kill-external?cb=1#comment21458_254893):

> Here's a not-as-contrived-as-it-seems analogy: you have a plot of land that is infested with a particular type of weed. It's obviously weed, no doubt about it. You annihilate that weed with some weedkiller. Then you find you've removed the only food source for a small animal you had no idea existed.

Small animals were definitely harmed by this purge and don't understand why their food source is considered to be weeds in the first place.

<sub>P.S.: it may have been `ietf-netconf` instead of `netconf` (if not, the former is a better alternative).</sub>

Comment: I can't find the usage of that tag in the history of still existing posts: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/506432?tag=netconf nor for the alternative [ietf-netconf](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/506432?tag=ietf-netconf). If there are no questions tagged with it (or the ones that were are deleted due to inactivity or closing/deleting) the tag will be removed by the clean-up script. if you have a question where you are absolutely sure the tag was on, a moderator can maybe see what happened.

Comment: @rene, not sure about specific questions, but I remember the tag disappearing from existing ones. It is true that there appear to be less questions mentioning `netconf` then I expected and were most likely deleted. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417534/java-netconf-library), although closed, may be a safe bet.

Comment: I have even created a network-wide search: http://stackexchange.com/filters/245468/netconf  those tags simply don't exist.

Comment: Unless magic happened that question never had the tag: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3417534/revisions

Comment: @rene, hmm.. I can't explain why I remember it existing.

Comment: Just blame the unicorns ... and let's wait for a mod or dev who can peek into deleted stuff.

Comment: I added the [netconf] tag.  You should write the wiki for it, I imagine linking to the RFC and the Wikipedia article ought to suffice.

Comment: @HansPassant, please name it `ietf-netconf`. I can imagine "netconf" being used for other things. It will also match `ietf-netmod-yang`, which is the other related tag I mentioned.

Comment: Strangely enough, the `netconf` tag had 10 followers as soon as it was created, which probably supports my claims of having seen it before. I've added a wiki for it, but would still prefer `ietf-netconf` over it.

Comment: Well, that would match all questions which ever had it being deleted over time, hopefully for good reason...

Comment: Predi you have enough reputation to edit the tag and use the correct naming. Do it now before it becomes too late

Comment: @Braiam, not quite sure what you mean. Create a new tag? It was already too late when Hans beat me to it.

Comment: Doesn't matter http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3417534/revisions

Comment: Just in case. I have adopted the `ietf-netconf` tag and re-tagged all NETCONF related questions with it. If any action is taken based on my question, please take that into account.